# why is a = [1,2,3] and a[:] not the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this below code

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a is b #shows True

b = a[:]
a is b #shows False
a == b # shows True
```

I thought the value of [1,2,3] and a[:] would have the same id and they are the exact same object.
What exactly happens when a[:] is assigned to b?
I'm sorry if this question has already been asked before, could not find a perfect answer

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/6849682

Comment: In future, please add a plain python tag in addition to the python-3.x tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a[:] is a shallow copy of a list (as a slice).   It has the same numeric value, but it is not the original list.   == Checks value, "is" is value and "identity" of the value.

Comment: Since it doesn't look like you've taken the tour yet, I'll clue you: please don't answer no-brainer questions like this until you check to see if it's a duplicate. If it hasn't already been answered go for it, but if it has flag it to be closed instead.

Comment: @TankorSmash I know, which is why I left a comment and didn't downvote/flag it. Although I see someone did. Ah well.

Comment: Thanks. The word "shallow copy" helped me understand the reason behind the difference.